# Redirect link on console output row to the callee of wrapper function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I have written a decorator/wrapper for `window.console` so that I, among other nifty stuff, can disable stray `console.log`'s in my production environment.
What i am experiencing is that my wrapper now appears as the source of the actual log command. This makes debugging through the console a bit of a hassle since clicking the link to the far right in the console only leads to my own output function.

The following code is a simplified version of the real script where i have removed some features like enabling/disabling and caching/flushing of rows that have been hidden.

```js
    //Save reference to original function
    var oConsole = window.console;

    //Create custom console output method
    var wConsole = function (method) {
        return function () {
            if (!window.console[method].enabled) {
                //Apply log command to original console method
                oConsole[method].apply(oConsole, Array.from(arguments)); //This is the row i get linked to
            }
        };
    };

    //Create a new console object for overriding original functions
    var overrides = {
        o: oConsole,
        log: wConsole("log"),
        debug: wConsole("debug"),
        info: wConsole("info"),
        warn: wConsole("warn"),
        error: wConsole("error")
    }

    //Using jQuery i create a new instance and extend my defined overrides onto the original version
    window.console = $.extend({}, window.console, overrides);

    console.log("test 123"); //This is the row i want to link to
```

When i click the link to the right...
[image]

...i get linked to this row.
[image]


Is there a way to make a function "transparent" in such a way that the link refers to the callee of my wrapper function instead?

The solution only needs to work in Google Chrome, since I perform the majority of my development there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has an option to "blackbox" script files. While this seems to be mostly intended to ignore framework scripts while debugging (blackboxed scripts will be skipped when stepping through code) it will help with your case as well since it will not show as the source for console output.

1. Open DevTools
2. Go to settings (F1 or through the main menu)
3. Open the Blackboxing tab
4. Enable the checkbox
5. Add a pattern that matches the file with your console override
6. Be happy

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/guides/blackbox-chrome-extension-scripts

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I was looking for.
Just need to do some preparationsto test it. Have to extract some functions to a separate file.